# Cloudify 3.3 - Use of existing network (no Floating IP)

Tags: openstack, cloudify, cloudify-script-plugin

we want to configure a Cloudify Manager into an OpenStack project in which there is only an external network (named public_net), with public IP addresses.
In other words, each Cloudify VM (both Manager and Application) should be attached to the external net (no Floating IP).
The Cloudify CLI, on the other hand, was created out of OpenStack.

How should we configure the OpenStack plugin to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloudify manager if bootstrapped with the Openstack blueprint will be configured to two networks:

1. The network that it can connect to the OpenStack API (external network)
2. A management network that it will create.

If you want to use the external network for the management network, you should change the blueprint so it will have this network as an external resource (external_resource: true) and set the name of the network to public_net.

your blueprint will look like this:

```
management_network:
type: cloudify.openstack.nodes.Network
properties:
  use_external_resource: true
  resource_id: public_net
  openstack_config: *openstack_configuration
```

Comment: Should I comment some part of the blueprint? For example: management_subnet:, manager_port:, etc...?

Comment: No, you will still use those

Comment: I think I should comment something. For example, in the "manager_server_ip:" node there is "type: cloudify.openstack.nodes.FloatingIP", and I don't want to use Floating IP. So, I think the entire blueprint has to be reviewd to comment many part of it.

Comment: I modified the blueprint as mentioned here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloudify-users/O8oCSTzMX6I

The cloudify-manager-server was created, but I receive an error about Fabric plugin.